# SharePoint 2013 Master Page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have this code for SharePoint 2013 for ASPX file and it is working, but for HTML Master page I converted and not working.

### This is the ASPX code.

```
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Url") %>'></asp:LinkButton><asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ChildMenuRepeater" DataSource='<%# ((SiteMapNode)Container.DataItem).ChildNodes %>'>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <ul id="SpNavChilds"></ul>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Url") %>'></asp:LinkButton></li>
                        </ItemTemplate>                     
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <ul></ul>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

### The Converted code is:

-->
                            -->-->
                                
                                    
                                        
                                            -->
                                                -->

```
                                                <!--MS:<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Url") %>'>--><!--ME:</asp:LinkButton>-->
                                                <!--MS:<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ChildMenuRepeater" DataSource="<%# ((SiteMapNode)Container.DataItem).ChildNodes %>">-->
                                                    <!--MS:<HeaderTemplate>-->
                                                        <ul id="SpNavChilds">
                                                    <!--ME:</HeaderTemplate>-->
                                                    <!--MS:<ItemTemplate>-->
                                                            <li><!--SPS:<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Url") %>'>--><!--ME:</asp:LinkButton>--></li>
                                                    <!--ME:</ItemTemplate>-->
                                                    <!--MS:<FooterTemplate>-->
                                                        </ul>
                                                    <!--ME:</FooterTemplate>-->
                                                    <!--ME:</asp:Repeater>-->
                                                </li>
                                            <!--ME:</ItemTemplate>-->
                                        <!--ME:</asp:Repeater>-->
                                    </ul>
                                </nav>   
                                <!--MS:<asp:SiteMapDataSource ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="CombinedNavSiteMapProvider" id="topSiteMap1" runat="server" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002" />-->
                            </div>
                            <!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: What error are you getting? "code blocks are not allowed in this file"? If yes then it is because sharepoint by default does not allow code blocks in customized master pages (by customized i mean those edited by sharepoint designer). You may need to deploy master page using feature to resolve this.

Comment: This is the Error: SharePoint can't parse this file, most likely because of an incorrectly formatted SharePoint snippet. The markup at the following location is causing problems. Edit the markup manually to fix it, or replace it with a new snippet from the Snippet Gallery.

Comment: It is not all master page code. Could you please post all your code?